# SpringToolSuite configuration

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, configuration, spring-tool-suite

I've just installed eclipse mars and then I installed springToolSuite from the eclipse marketplace.

I want to create spring project, just a helloworld to get used to the whole thing, can you please tell me what to do ? is there any other steps I need to follow ? what about configurations ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are bunch of 'hello-world-ish' samples at your fingertips. Select Menu "New >> Import Spring Getting Started Content" and try "Getting Started Guide" called "Rest Service".

[image]

It will import two projects a 'initial' and mostly empty one and 'complete' one with the end point of short sequence of steps in a mini tutorial to create a simple 'hello world' Rest Service with Spring Boot.

It will also open the web page for the mini-tutorial.